# Ejecutar método desde un TextBox

Tags: c#

En un TextBox pongo la lectura de un lector de código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que me trae el lector de código **18300-50** no siempre trae esto va variando **18300-600** ,**19100-850** etc.

Yo tengo un botón que captura estos datos y trabajo con ellos para hacer las consultas en SQL SERVER,
pero para disparar el método que hace esas consultas tengo un botón,
es decir se pone el código se oprime el botón y trae la información lo que necesito es que sea automático que cuando en el TextBox este la información del código  este automáticamente se dispare sin apretar nada que el automáticamente se dispare cuando el lector de código pone la información

```
  private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = null;

            try
            {

                string numero = txtVariables.Text;
                string lote = numero.Substring(0, numero.IndexOf("-"));
                string canal = numero.Substring(numero.IndexOf("-") + 1);
                decimal peso = decimal.Parse(TxtPeso.Text);


                dt = consultas.CanalesContadas(lote, canal);


                dt = consultas.CanalesPesadas(lote, canal);

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Pesadas = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                }



                dt = consultas.CanalesCerradas(lote);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    CanalesCerradas = bool.Parse(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
                }



                if (CanalesCerradas == false)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Pesadas))
                    {
                        consultas.InsertarPeso(peso, lote, canal);
                        dt = consultas.Cantidades(lote);
                        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            lblLote.Text = lote;
                            lblRestantes.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                            lblPesados.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                            lblCanal.Text = canal;
                            lblNumeroCanales.Text = dt.Rows[0][5].ToString();
                            lblPremium.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
                        }
                        dt = consultas.Diferencias(lote, canal);
                        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            lblPesoCaliente.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                            lblPesoFrio.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                            lblDiferencia.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
                            CanalPremium = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][3].ToString());
                            if (CanalPremium == 2)
                            {
                                lblMessage.Text = "¡Esta canal es premium!";
                            }
                            else
                                lblMessage.Text = "";
                        }

                        dt = consultas.DiferenciasDePeso(lote, canal);
                        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            Diferencia = decimal.Parse(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
                        }



                        if (Diferencia >= 12)
                        {
                            lblDiferenciaPeso.Text = "El peso de canal caliente supera los 12kg del peso frio  " + Diferencia;
                        }


                        if (Diferencia < 0)
                        {
                            lblDiferenciaPeso.Text = "El peso frio es mayor que el peso caliente  " + Diferencia;
                        }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Esta Canal ya esta pesada");
                        Limpiar();
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Este lote ya tiene cerrado el peso cava");
                    Limpiar();
                }


                dt = consultas.CanalesPesadasAPP(lote);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    lblContadasCodtipo.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                }

            }
```

Todo lo que hace este botón lo necesito pero que el TextBox detecte que ya esta la información y dispare todo esto

```
   private void txtVariables_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

¿Que evento debo utilizar o como puedo lograr esto?

Comment: que lector de codigo de barra utilizas? lo pregunto porque esto que quieres hacer se configura en el lector, puedes definirle que luego de la lectura ingrese ingrese un `Tab` o un `Enter`, entonces utilizas los evento LostFocus o KeyPress (detectando el enter) segun sea el caso y alli realizas la busqueda

Comment: Pero como el lector esta en un proceso que la  temperatura es muy baja lo mantienen cambiando por daños entonces no se puede definir uno pero  se que casi todos son zebra

Comment: no importa cuanto lo cambien, todas las marcas de todos lo modelos tienen esta funcionalidad que se puede configurar, solo lee el manual para aprender como hacerlo https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/evm/add-a-tab-key-after-scanning-a-bar-code.html sino contacta el soporte de zebra

Comment: Muchas gracias @LeandroTuttini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar una expresión regular, casi no se utilizan y son una gran herramienta.

```
private void txtVariables_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Codigo = @"\d{5}-\d{2}";
        Regex miRegex = new Regex(Codigo, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (miRegex.IsMatch(txtVariables.Text))
        {
            Consulta();
        }
    }

    public static void Consulta()
    {
        DataTable dt = null;

        try
        {

            string numero = txtVariables.Text;
            string lote = numero.Substring(0, numero.IndexOf("-"));
            string canal = numero.Substring(numero.IndexOf("-") + 1);
            decimal peso = decimal.Parse(TxtPeso.Text);


            dt = consultas.CanalesContadas(lote, canal);


            dt = consultas.CanalesPesadas(lote, canal);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Pesadas = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            }



            dt = consultas.CanalesCerradas(lote);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                CanalesCerradas = bool.Parse(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
            }



            if (CanalesCerradas == false)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Pesadas))
                {
                    consultas.InsertarPeso(peso, lote, canal);
                    dt = consultas.Cantidades(lote);
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        lblLote.Text = lote;
                        lblRestantes.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                        lblPesados.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                        lblCanal.Text = canal;
                        lblNumeroCanales.Text = dt.Rows[0][5].ToString();
                        lblPremium.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
                    }
                    dt = consultas.Diferencias(lote, canal);
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        lblPesoCaliente.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                        lblPesoFrio.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                        lblDiferencia.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
                        CanalPremium = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][3].ToString());
                        if (CanalPremium == 2)
                        {
                            lblMessage.Text = "¡Esta canal es premium!";
                        }
                        else
                            lblMessage.Text = "";
                    }

                    dt = consultas.DiferenciasDePeso(lote, canal);
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Diferencia = decimal.Parse(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
                    }



                    if (Diferencia >= 12)
                    {
                        lblDiferenciaPeso.Text = "El peso de canal caliente supera los 12kg del peso frio  " + Diferencia;
                    }


                    if (Diferencia < 0)
                    {
                        lblDiferenciaPeso.Text = "El peso frio es mayor que el peso caliente  " + Diferencia;
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Esta Canal ya esta pesada");
                    Limpiar();
                }
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Este lote ya tiene cerrado el peso cava");
                Limpiar();
            }


            dt = consultas.CanalesPesadasAPP(lote);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                lblContadasCodtipo.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```